# Django redirecting to wrong view in other app

Tags: python, django

After adding an other app to my django 1.6 project I ran into a strange problem with the HttpResponseRedirect function of django.

I have a login view for both of the apps but when I try to login to the second app I got redirected to first_app/list instead to second_app/index.

so in my first app the view is

```
def login(request):

aut_form = auth.forms.AuthenticationForm()
if(request.method == 'POST'):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fist_app:list'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fist_app:login') + '?loggedout')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fist_app:login') + '?invalid')
else: 
    return render(request, 'first_app/login.html', {'form' : aut_form})

def list(request):

if  request.user is None or not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fist_app:login'))
else:     
    return response
```

and in the second app the views.py looks pretty much the same

```
def login(request):

aut_form = auth.forms.AuthenticationForm()
if(request.method == 'POST'):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
            print("success")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('second_app:index'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('second_app:login') + '?loggedout')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('second_app:login') + '?invalid')
else: 
    return render(request, 'second_app/login.html', {'form' : aut_form})

def index(request):
return render(request, 'second_app/index.html')
```

I also checked my urls.py in both apps of regular expressions that are too vague.

urls.py of first_app

```
urlpatterns = patterns('first_app.views',
    url(r'^list/$', views.list, name='list' ),
    url(r'^login$', views.login, name='login'),
)
```

urls.py of second app

```
urlpatterns = patterns('second_app.views',
   url(r'^login$', views.login, name='login'),
   url(r'^index$', views.index, name="index"),
)
```

What do I have to change to get redirected to the correct view in the login-page related app?

and my projects urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^backend/', include('second_app.urls', namespace="second_app")),
    url(r'^polls/', include('first_app.urls', namespace="first_app")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Show your main URL conf where you are including app urls

Comment: I think you always end up on the first view (unless there is a prefix to you `login` pattern) because, I suspect, it's the first one in your `urls.py`.

Comment: I've add the project urls.py to the question field. Unfortunately I already tried to change the app order in the global urls.py file to avoid this error. Is there an other workaround?

Comment: I guess the problem is in `login.html`. How you are adding URL in form `action`?

Comment: Ahhhh you got it. I must have forgotten to change the action in the login form after I copied the template file from the first app to the second. You can post this as answer.

Comment: @BlueSapphire posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at code snippets you have shared. The only possible reason I can guess is that you are not using app specific `login` URL in template `login.html` under form `action`.